# drawInRect:withFont:lineBreakMode:alignment deprecation in IOS 7

Tags: ios7, cocos2d-iphone, drawinrect

I have a message of deprecated method.

The line of code is this one :

```
[string drawInRect:drawArea withFont:uifont lineBreakMode:linebreaks[lineBreakMode] alignment:alignments[hAlignment]];
```

So I want to replace it with this code :

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

NSDictionary *attributes = @{ NSFontAttributeName: uifont,
                              NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle};

[string drawInRect:drawArea withAttributes:attributes];
```

After this replacement, the warning is not here anymore. But, all my text is invisible. For example, I have a text "Options" which is not visible (but I can still click on it).

Someone can help on this please?

Regard

Comment: Have you tried changing contextRGB color for example following CGContextRef    currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(currentContext,0,0,0,1);